# Invoke Spring controller method on redirect FROM jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, methods

So let assume I have 2 jsp files:
login.jsp and menu.jsp

Also I have two methods in the controller class:

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
    public void login() {
        return "login";
    }


@RequestMapping("/menu")
    public void menu() {
        List<User> allUsers = userJpaRepository.findAll();
    return new ModelAndView("allUsers", "users", allUsers);
    }
```

In **login.jsp**

```
<%@page import="com.markovski.database.DataBase"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<form method="get" action="menu.jsp">
<% 
    String accname = request.getParameter("uname");
    String password = request.getParameter("pass");

    if(DataBase.checkForUserCreditinals(accname, password)){
        session.setAttribute("userId", 2);

        response.sendRedirect("menu.jsp");
    } else {
        //out.println("Error");
    }

%>
</form>
```

So what do I want ? When I log in I would like to be redirected to menu page, but it does not invoke menu(), which will pass all users to my menu.jsp. So it is just opening an empty /menu page. How can I redirect to menu.jsp AND INVOKE the controller method, which will give me the data that I want to display ?

Comment: Do you use Spring security to manage your login process?

Comment: You can invoke menu method like `response.sendRedirect("/menu")` and return like `return new ModelAndView("menu", "users", allUsers)` from that method.

Comment: @akuma8, no I do not. It is custom created.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly call the controller to display your results since the method is called anyway if you visit /menu.
[This](http://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login) covers it pretty well.

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt Your method was right ! :) Thank you.

Comment: @Artur Yes, so my mistake was that I was redirecting to "menu.jsp" not "/menu"

Comment: If I were you, I'll consider using Spring security for this, since you are using Spring mvc. Anyway, why in `login.jsp` you have this `action="menu.jsp"`? You should have an uri example `action="/menu"` not the page name.

Comment: @akuma8 I am pretty newbie with Spring MVC and I am still learning :) About the MVC Authenticator, i tried but failed a couple of times. So i will check it later.

Comment: If you are still learning, just an advice, avoid scriptlet (Java code in JSP files), it's messy !

Comment: Yes, now I can call the controller method, and there will be the java code :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are coding in Spring, I think we can stick to it than mixing jsp and Spring style. Why don't you write  a mapping for menu url and return menu.jsp from it. Also you can keep your database code as well there ( though not a good practice). You may also need to handle the login submissions as well.